# Stack Tracing Considering the ARM assembly language version mentioned below

Tags: assembly, arm, stack-trace, armasm

[part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sldJ.jpg)
[part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNGPt.jpg)
Confused on how to trace the changes to the stack.

Need to show every instruction that affects the stack, the location of the stack or the frame pointer (all of the highlighted instructions). For each of these instructions, show the full contents of the stack after the instruction has been executed.

Using the table below.

| Address | Value |
| --- | --- |
| FFFF FFAC |  |
| FFFF FFB0 |  |
| FFFF FFB4 |  |
| FFFF FFB8 |  |
| FFFF FFBC |  |
| FFFF FFC0 |  |
| FFFF FFC4 |  |
| FFFF FFC8 |  |
| FFFF FFCC |  |
| FFFF FFD0 |  |
| FFFF FFD4 |  |
| FFFF FFD8 |  |
| FFFF FFDC |  |
| FFFF FFE0 |  |
| FFFF FFE4 |  |
| FFFF FFE8 |  |
| FFFF FFEC |  |
| FFFF FFF0 |  |
| FFFF FFF4 |  |
| FFFF FFF8 |  |
| FFFF FFFC |  |
| Instruction | ___________ |

```
 AREA MULTIPLY_STACK, CODE, READONLY
 ENTRY
START LDR FP, FPS ; (0)
 MOV SP, #0 ; (4)
 BL MAIN ; (8)
DONE B DONE ; (12)
MAIN PUSH {FP, LR} ; (16)
 SUB SP, SP, #16 ; (20)
 ADD FP, SP, #0 ; (24)
 ADR R10, RESULT ; (28)
 LDR R3, NUM1 ; (32)
 STR R3, [FP, #4] ; (36)
 LDR R3, NUM2 ; (40)
 STR R3, [FP, #8] ; (44)
 LDR R1, [FP, #8] ; (48)
 LDR R0, [FP, #4] ; (52)
 BL MPY_NE ; (56)
 STR R0, [R10] ; (60)
 MOV R3, R0 ; (64)
 STR R3, [FP, #12] ; (68)
 MOVS R3, #0 ; (72)
 MOV R0, R3 ; (76)
 ADDS FP, FP, #16 ; (80)
 MOV SP, FP ; (84)
 POP {FP, PC} ; (88)
MPY_NE PUSH {FP, LR} ; (92)
 SUB SP, SP, #24 ; (96)
 ADD FP, SP, #0 ; (100)
 STR R0, [FP, #4] ; (104)
 STR R1, [FP] ; (108)
 LDR R3, [FP, #4] ; (112)
 BL ABS ; (116)
 STR R0, [FP, #16] ; (120)
 LDR R3, [FP] ; (124)
 BL ABS ; (128)
 STR R0, [FP, #20] ; (132)
 MOVS R3, #0 ; (136)
 STR R3, [FP, #8] ; (140)
 MOVS R3, #0 ; (144)
 STR R3, [FP, #12] ; (148)
L5 LDR R2, [FP, #12] ; (152)
 LDR R3, [FP, #16] ; (156)
 CMP R2, R3 ; (160)
 BGE L4 ; (164)
 LDR R2, [FP, #8] ; (168)
 LDR R3, [FP, #20] ; (172)
 ADD R3, R3, R2 ; (176)
 STR R3, [FP, #8] ; (180)
 LDR R3, [FP, #12] ; (184)
 ADDS R3, R3, #1 ; (188)
 STR R3, [FP, #12] ; (192)
 B L5 ; (196)
L4 LDR R3, [FP, #4] ; (200)
 CMP R3, #0 ; (204)
 BGE L6 ; (208)
 LDR R3, [FP, #8] ; (212)
 NEGS R3, R3 ; (216)
STR R3, [FP, #8] ; (220)
L6 LDR R3, [FP] ; (224)
 CMP R3, #0 ; (228)
 BGE L7 ; (232)
 LDR R3, [FP, #8] ; (236)
 NEGS R3, R3 ; (240)
 STR R3, [FP, #8] ; (244)
L7 LDR R3, [FP, #8] ; (248)
 MOV R0, R3 ; (252)
 ADDS FP, FP, #24 ; (256)
 MOV SP, FP ; (260)
 POP {FP, PC} ; (264)
ABS PUSH {FP} ; (268)
 CMP R3, #0 ; (272)
 BGE L10 ; (276)
 NEGS R3, R3 ; (280) 
L10 MOV R0, R3 ; (284)
 LDR FP, [SP], #4 ; (288)
 BX LR ; (292)
NUM1 DCD -5 ; (296)
NUM2 DCD -11 ; (300)
RESULT SPACE 4 ; (304)
FPS DCD 0XFFFFFFA0 ; (308)
 END
```

I tried analyzing it and looking at the professor’s notes but I can not understand how to start or read it.

I started with this but I do not think it’s right.

| Address | Value |
| --- | --- |
| FFFF FFAC | 0xFFFFFFA0 |
| FFFF FFB0 |  |
| FFFF FFB4 |  |
| FFFF FFB8 |  |
| FFFF FFBC |  |
| FFFF FFC0 |  |
| FFFF FFC4 |  |
| FFFF FFC8 |  |
| FFFF FFCC |  |
| FFFF FFD0 |  |
| FFFF FFD4 |  |
| FFFF FFD8 |  |
| FFFF FFDC |  |
| FFFF FFE0 |  |
| FFFF FFE4 |  |
| FFFF FFE8 |  |
| FFFF FFEC |  |
| FFFF FFF0 |  |
| FFFF FFF4 |  |
| FFFF FFF8 |  |
| FFFF FFFC |  |
| Instruction | LDR FP, FPS ;(0) |

Comment: You identified the proper value, however, the target of an `LDR` instruction is not stack memory, but rather a register, here, the `FP` register.  The assignment wants you to capture values written to the stack — and in order to do that you'll have to track what values are in what registers, as, for example, registers are pushed onto the stack.

Comment: So using PUSH/POP? Meaning I'd have five tables?

Comment: How did you count 5 tables? I count only two: one for memory and one for the registers (there's ~16 of them).  But yeah, you have to pretend to be the computer and work each instruction, whether its effect on memory, registers, and/or control flow.

Comment: A table for each instruction that modifies the stack… push/pop so five? And then do mov and sub modify it as well?

Comment: You should be able to share the same two table for all instructions.  One table for memory (stack) and one table for registers.  That's how the real processor will work: modifying program state by one instruction via changes to memory or cpu registers, so that the next instruction has this new state to work from.

Comment: I need to show each change that each instruction makes. How do I do that with one table?

Comment: So for the first instruction that modifies the stack? | Address    | Value                        |
|------------|------------------------------|
| FFFF FFF4  | LR (Return address to caller of MAIN) |
| FFFF FFF8  | FP (Initial value of FP)     |
| FFFF FFFC  | [Top of Stack before MAIN]   |

Comment: You may be better than I, but I find it almost impossible to read assembly (or any other code other than a header declaring constants) when it is written in ALL CAPS. Try lower-case. You may find it much easier on the eyes (especially older sets...)